# BigQuery - JSON_EXTRACT only extracts first entry

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have a column containing a json-string as follows:

```
[{"answer":"europe-austria-swiss","text":"Österreich, Schweiz"},{"answer":"europe-italy","text":"Italien"},{"answer":"europe-france","text":"Frankreich"}]
```

I want to extract ALL answers given in ONE column and row, seperated by a comma:

```
europe-austria-swiss, europe-italy, europe-france
```

I think I tried all possibilites offered by JSON_EXTRACT and JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY or replacing parentheses and other signs, but I either only get the first entry extracted (in this case

```
europe-austria-swiss
```

) or it splits up in rows as array from which I can no longer extract the strings of "answer".

Has anyone any idea on how to solve that problem? It's very much appreciated!
This column is of course part of a much larger table (if that is relevant anyhow).

Comment: Your data structure is unclear.  Do you have an array of JSON objects?  Or a JSON with an array?  Also show the code you are using now.

Comment: It's a json array which contains json objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(answer, '$.answer'), ' ,') 
  FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string)) answer
  ) AS answers 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '[{"answer":"europe-austria-swiss","text":"Österreich, Schweiz"},{"answer":"europe-italy","text":"Italien"},{"answer":"europe-france","text":"Frankreich"}]' json_string
)
SELECT (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(answer, '$.answer'), ' ,') 
  FROM UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json_string)) answer
  ) AS answers 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row answers
1   europe-austria-swiss ,europe-italy ,europe-france
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what's going on (please, correct me if I'm wrong).

My best guess is that you are trying something like:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.answer") AS answers
FROM UNNEST([
'{"answer":"europe-austria-swiss","text":"Österreich, Schweiz"},{"answer":"europe-italy","text":"Italien"},{"answer":"europe-france","text":"Frankreich"}'
]) as json_text
```

This returns:

```
"europe-austria-swiss"
```

However, if you change the underlying data for something like this (each line as a json string object), it should resolve the issue:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, "$.answer") AS answers
FROM UNNEST([
'{"answer":"europe-austria-swiss","text":"Österreich, Schweiz"}',
'{"answer":"europe-italy","text":"Italien"}',
'{"answer":"europe-france","text":"Frankreich"}'
]) as json_text
```

Result:

```
"europe-austria-swiss"
"europe-italy"
"europe-france"
```

Hope this helps!